# R recursively modifying list, matching criteria

Tags: r

I've got a list like this (there's several other learners in it):

```
> predictions
$xgboost
Prediction: 178 observations
predict.type: prob
threshold: 0=0.50,1=0.50
time: 0.00
   id truth      prob.1      prob.0 response
4   1     1 0.997812952 0.002187048        1
6   2     0 0.012360513 0.987639487        0
10  3     1 0.972333297 0.027666703        1
15  4     0 0.001351058 0.998648942        0
17  5     0 0.036538243 0.963461757        0
18  6     1 0.160634995 0.839365005        0
... (#rows: 178, #cols: 5)

$ksvm
Prediction: 178 observations
predict.type: prob
threshold: 0=0.50,1=0.50
time: 0.08
   id truth     prob.0    prob.1 response
4   1     1 0.09893675 0.9010633        1
6   2     0 0.81784007 0.1821599        0
10  3     1 0.06813734 0.9318627        1
15  4     0 0.33309189 0.6669081        1
17  5     0 0.82915097 0.1708490        0
18  6     1 0.81119989 0.1888001        0
... (#rows: 178, #cols: 5)
```

And a list like this, with the thresholds:

```
> threshold
$`1`
$`1`$xgboost
[1] 0.8873576

$`1`$ksvm
[1] 0.7010678

$`0`
$`0`$xgboost
[1] 0.1126424

$`0`$ksvm
[1] 0.2989322
```

One can access the thresholds in `predictions` with `lapply(predictions, function(x) x[[3]])` which gives:

```
> lapply(predictions, function(x) x[[3]])
$xgboost
  0   1 
0.5 0.5 

$ksvm
  0   1 
0.5 0.5
```

**Question**:
how can i replace `predictions` thresholds with the ones in `threshold`?

Comment: YOu can use `Map` i.e. `Map(function(x, y) {x[[3]] <-  unlist(y); x}  , predictions, threshold)`

Comment: The approach above should work, although it looks like you need to use `purrr::transpose(threshold)` as the third argument instead. However, I wonder if this is a good idea. I don't know what kind of object this is or how it will be used, but it looks to me like you are going to create a list of predictions which say they are from a model with a different threshold than the one which produced them?

Comment: @IceCreamToucan  You are right.  I was also thinking about the structure but couldn't test it

Comment: @IceCreamToucan, since i have the probs, next step is to manually update response based on new thresholds. I'm doing this cause `makeTuneControlGrid(tune.threshold = TRUE)` appears to be broken in mlr package, cause all my thresholds are deafults (0.5).